# How can I cite like this?

Tags: bibtex, citing

So I have this problem, I want to cite two or more references in one sentence like this:

> (Author, year; Author, year)

I don't know how to do this, I tried using something like this but it's obviously wrong:

> \cite{blabla; blabla}

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use multiple citations in the same sentence using: `\cite{reference1,reference2,...,referenceN}`

Make sure to use `\usepackage{cite}`

Comment: Thank you so much!I don't know why I didn't try using comma instead of semicolon!

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a citation management package. The `cite` citation management package is suitable for numeric-styel citation call-outs. To generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, it's better to employ the `natbib` citation management package, to load it with the option `authoryear`, and to use a bibliography style that's capable of generating authoryear-style citation call-outs. I suggest you use the `plainnat` style until you get the hang of things.